# SQL - Selecting a column value based on max value in another column and combination of values in another column - Teradata

Tags: sql, select, teradata

My input Teradata table accnt_pln_info sample data is as below.

```
Account_number   Plan_code   Plan_Date    Base_Amount     Biz_Date
ACCT1            R           2017-JAN-01         100      2017-MAY-31
ACCT1            R           2017-JAN-11          30      2017-MAY-31
ACCT1            K           2017-JAN-22          80      2017-MAY-31
ACCT1            B           2017-JAN-13          50      2017-MAY-31
ACCT1            C           2017-JAN-18         180      2017-MAY-31
ACCT2            R           2017-JAN-12          70      2017-MAY-31
ACCT2            C           2017-JAN-02          90      2017-MAY-31
ACCT2            R           2017-JAN-08          10      2017-MAY-31
ACCT2            D           2017-JAN-02          40      2017-MAY-31
ACCT2            B           2017-FEB-24          14      2017-MAY-31
ACCT2            K           2017-FEB-12          79      2017-MAY-31
```

Desired output: (For filter condition Biz_Date=2017-MAY-31

```
Account_number   RK_Plan_Date    RK_Base_Amount   RC_Plan_Date   RC_Base_Amount
ACCT1            2017-JAN-22          80          2017-JAN-18         180
ACCT2            2017-FEB-12          79          2017-JAN-12          70
```

Logic:

```
Filter condition applied Biz_Date=2017-MAY-31 as table has multiple distinct biz_dates.
Group by Account_Number;  Plan_Date in (R,K), 
find the max Plan_Date and then get that rows Base_Amount; 
Plan_Date in (R,C), find the max Plan_Date and 
then get that rows Base_Amount.
```

eg:
For ACCT1, and plan_code in ('R','K'), the max plan_date values is 2017-JAN-22;  Hence need to get Base_amount of that row which is 80

Assumptions:

```
There can be duplicates on Account_number and Plan_Code.
There will not be duplicates on Account_number, Plan_Code in (R,K) and Plan_Date.
There will not be duplicates on Account_number, Plan_Code in (R,C) and Plan_Date.
The input order in table is not necessarily the same.
```

What I have tried and failed:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, 
MAX(CASE WHEN PLAN_DATE IN ('R','K') THEN PLAN_DATE END) MAX_RK_PLAN_DATE,
MAX(CASE WHEN PLAN_DATE IN ('R','K') AND MAX_PLAN_DATE=PLAN_DATE THEN BASE_AMOUNT END) REQUIRED_RK_AMOUNT,
MAX(CASE WHEN PLAN_DATE IN ('R','C') THEN PLAN_DATE END) MAX_RC_PLAN_DATE,
MAX(CASE WHEN PLAN_DATE IN ('R','C') AND MAX_PLAN_DATE=PLAN_DATE THEN BASE_AMOUNT END) REQUIRED_RC_AMOUNT 
FROM ACCNT_PLN_INFO;
```

As expected, it has failed as I am nesting aggregate function into a normal case statement.
I thought of using the chunks of data by splitting it as

```
SELECT ....
(SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, 'RK', 
MAX(PLAN_DATE) MAX_RK_PLAN_DATE FROM ACCNT_PLN_INFO WHERE 
PLAN_DATE IN ('R','K') 
UNION 
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, 'RC', 
MAX(PLAN_DATE) MAX_RC_PLAN_DATE FROM ACCNT_PLN_INFO WHERE 
PLAN_DATE IN ('R','C') )
```

and wanted to join to outer select from the same table again.  But due to the different possible combinations of(R.K) and (R,C) I am not able do that.  I know how to achieve it when there are no combinations involved.

For convenience, I had specified only 2 combinations with 2 values as PLAN_DATE IN ('R','K');   PLAN_DATE IN ('R','C').  But actually there are 6 combinations and each combination will have 4 values.

I had tried whatever I could do to achieve this.  But unfortunately, couldn't.  How to select a column value when we need a multiple combination of values and max of a column value.  Thank you for your precious time.

Comment: How many distinct `Account_number` exist & how many rows for a `Biz_Date` qualify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an approach which is similar to the aggregation you tried applying a dirty ol' trick, *piggybacking*.

You combine both columns into a single string, apply MAX and then strip off the date part again, e.g. for `ACCT1` combining both `PLAN_DATE` & `BASE_AMOUNT` into a single string will result in this:

```
'20170101        100'
'20170111         30'
'20170113         50'
'20170118        180'
'20170122         80' -- this will be returned by MAX
```

After applying max you extract both columns again using SUBSTRING:

```
   CAST(SUBSTR('2017-01-22         80', 1, 10) AS DATE)
   CAST(SUBSTR('2017-01-22         80', 11) AS INT)
```

Of course you must create a string which is still sorting the correct way, e.g. `yyyymmdd` for a date and fixed width including leading spaces for numeric.

Now it's some Cut&Paste&Modify:

```
SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
   To_Date(Substr(RK, 1,8), 'yyyymmdd') AS MAX_RK_PLAN_DATE,
   Cast(Substring(RK From 9) AS INT) AS REQUIRED_RK_AMOUNT,
   To_Date(Substr(RC, 1,8), 'yyyymmdd') AS MAX_RC_PLAN_DATE,
   Cast(Substring(RC From 9) AS INT) AS REQUIRED_RC_AMOUNT
FROM 
 ( 
   SELECT ACCOUNT_NUMBER, 
      Max(CASE WHEN PLAN_code IN ('R','K') THEN To_Char(PLAN_DATE, 'yyyymmdd') || BASE_AMOUNT END) AS RK,
      Max(CASE WHEN PLAN_code IN ('R','C') THEN To_Char(PLAN_DATE, 'yyyymmdd') || BASE_AMOUNT END) AS RC
   FROM ACCNT_PLN_INFO
   WHERE  biz_date = DATE '2017-05-31'
   GROUP BY 1
 ) AS dt
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew and Dnoeth for your valuable info.  :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  Rewrote using qualify.

You need to get the max plan date for each plan_code pairing.  You can do that in two separate derived tables, using `qualify` to get the data for the max plan date.  Then you can join those two results together using account_number.

```
select
rk.account_number,
rk_plan_date,
rk.base_amount as rk_base_amount,
rc.rc_plan_date,
rc.base_amount as rc_base_amount
from
(
select
    ACCNT_PLN_INFO.account_number,
    ACCNT_PLN_INFO.plan_date as rk_plan_date,
    base_amount
from 
    ACCNT_PLN_INFO
where
    plan_code in ('R','K')
qualify row_number() over (partition by ACCNT_PLN_INFO.account_number order by plan_date desc) = 1
) rk
inner join 
(select
    ACCNT_PLN_INFO.account_number,
    ACCNT_PLN_INFO.plan_date as rc_plan_date,
    base_amount
from 
    ACCNT_PLN_INFO
where
    plan_code in ('R','C')
qualify row_number() over (partition by ACCNT_PLN_INFO.account_number order by plan_date desc) = 1
)RC
on RK.account_number = rc.account_number
```

Original (non teradata specific syntax):

```
select
rk.account_number,
rk_plan_date,
rk.base_amount as rk_base_amount,
rc.rc_plan_date,
rc.base_amount as rc_base_amount
from (
    select
    ACCNT_PLN_INFO.account_number,
    ACCNT_PLN_INFO.plan_date as rk_plan_date,
    base_amount
    from 
    ACCNT_PLN_INFO
    inner join (
    select
    account_number,
    max(plan_date) as plan_date
    from
    ACCNT_PLN_INFO
    where
    plan_code in ('R','K')
    group by 1) rk
        on ACCNT_PLN_INFO.account_number = rk.account_number
        and ACCNT_PLN_INFO.plan_date = rk.plan_date
        and ACCNT_PLN_INFO.plan_code in ('R','K')
) RK
inner join (    
select
ACCNT_PLN_INFO.account_number,
ACCNT_PLN_INFO.plan_date as rc_plan_date,
base_amount
from 
ACCNT_PLN_INFO
inner join (
select
account_number,
max(plan_date) as plan_date
from
ACCNT_PLN_INFO
where
plan_code in ('R','C')
group by 1) rc
    on ACCNT_PLN_INFO.account_number = rc.account_number
    and ACCNT_PLN_INFO.plan_date = rc.plan_date
    and ACCNT_PLN_INFO.plan_code in ('C','R')
) RC
on RK.account_number = rc.account_number
```